# c++11 threads: unable to stop thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I'm learning to use threads in c++11 (I've mostly used threads via some framework but not directly).

Here's a simple class that runs the `run()` method in a new thread. The `start()`/`stop()` method are used for controlling the threads lifecycle:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

class ThreadTest
{
public:
    ThreadTest() : _run(false), _t(nullptr) {}
    void start()
    {   
        lock_guard<mutex> g(_mutex);
        cout << "Starting new thread..." << endl;
        _run = true;
        if (!_t) {
            _t.reset(new thread(&ThreadTest::run, this));
        }
    }

    void stop()
    {   
        lock_guard<mutex> g(_mutex); 
        cout << "Stopping thread..." << endl;
        _run = false;
        if (_t) {
            _t->join();
            _t.reset(nullptr);
        }
    }

    void run()
    {   
        while(true) {
            lock_guard<mutex> g(_mutex);
            if (!_run) {
                return;
            }
            cout << "Running every sec" << endl;
            sleep(1);
        } 
   }

private:
    atomic<bool> _run;
    unique_ptr<thread> _t;
    mutex _mutex;
};

int main()
{
    ThreadTest t;
    t.start();
    cout << "Sleeping for 2 secs..." << endl;
    sleep(2);
    cout << "Done" << endl;
    t.stop();
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Starting new thread...
Sleeping for 2 secs...
Running every sec
Running every sec
Done
Running every sec
Running every sec
Running every sec
Running every sec
```

The problem is that the thread does *NOT* stop after calling `stop()`! On debugging I found that its stuck in this function trying to acquire the lock `_mutex` and therefore the `_run` variable is not set to `false` yet. I know that since `_run` is an `atomic`, I dont strictly need locks here, but I'm trying to understand the usage of locks here.

Shouldn't the mutex be acquired whenever the `while` loop of `run()` loops again?

For the life of me I can't explain this trivial issue! :/

Comment: Since `_run` is an `atomic` variable, you don't need a lock or a mutex to protect it. Any changes to it, or reading of its values, will be *atomic*.

Comment: Ok, so I found the bug. It was because of the way I'm holding lock in my `stop()` function. I should limit it's scope only while I'm modifying `_run`. Something like `{
        lock_guard<mutex> g(_mutex); 
        _run = false;
        }`

Comment: Try putting braces around everything in the run method except for sleep function.

Comment: Or just remove the mutex and the locks altogether.

Comment: g keeps lock in while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug (s).

In the `stop()` function, I should limit the scope of the lock duration:

```
void stop()
{   
    {
    lock_guard<mutex> g(_mutex); 
    _run = false;
    }
    if (_t) {
        _t->join();
        _t.reset(nullptr);
    }
}
```

And also in the main loop of the `run()` function, I should hold the lock only while checking the value of `_run` (and not while `sleep`ing)

```
void run()
{   
    while(true) {
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> g(_mutex);
            if (!_run) {
                return;
            }
        }
        cout << "Running every sec" << endl;
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to be nagging, but *why* do you want to keep the unnecessary mutex and locks? Perhaps you should do some more research about atomic operations and [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)?

Comment: As I said, this is only a sample program. I wrote it to explain an issue I was facing when using condition variables & mutex's. For simple loop control, yes I can use an atomic and not worry about locks. However, in my main program I'm trying to serialize access to a queue and hence the need.